# Check if delegate method was called

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, nsstream

I have following function for connecting to a TCP Socket (Server on a Raspberry Pi, which I directly connect to via Access Point)

```
func connect (host: String, port: Int) {
    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: addr, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
    if outputStream != nil && inputStream != nil {
        outputStream!.delegate = self
        inputStream!.delegate = self
        outputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        inputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream!.open()
        inputStream!.open()
    }
}
```

When I'm connected to the Wifi-Hotspot of the Raspberry Pi following delegate method gets called and I can start writing data:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    if aStream === inputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
            print("input: ErrorOccurred: \(aStream.streamError?.localizedDescription)")
            self.Label.text = "Disconnected"
        case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
            print("input: OpenCompleted")
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            print("input: HasBytesAvailable")
            // Here you can `read()` from `inputStream`

        default:
            break
        }
    }
    else if aStream === outputStream {
        switch eventCode {
        case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
            print("output: ErrorOccurred: \(aStream.streamError?.localizedDescription)")
            self.Label.text = "Disconnected"
        case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
            print("output: OpenCompleted")
        case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
            // print("output: HasSpaceAvailable")
            // Here you can write() to `outputStream`
            self.write(f: l)
            self.write(f: r)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm connected to another WiFi this method doesn't get called.
How can I detect that this method didn't get called, so I can alert the user that he isn't connected and that he should try connecting again?

Comment: Detect how? I'm assuming a print/alertcontroller/assert wouldn't work?

Comment: write some code that detects if the stream() method is called and if it isn't called, I want to use an alert to notify the user that he is connected to the wrong network

Comment: @Daniel Gretzke use breakpoint.

Comment: Detecting if a method is called is easy: put a print, message, breakpoint, or whatever you like, at the beginning of the method definition. Detecting when a method is not called is still dependent on the context: where is the stream method called in code? Is it in a block with a completion and error handler? Because that is where you will likely need to add code, not in the method itself. Can you show the code where the delegate method is actually called?

Comment: stream(_:handle:) is called in StreamDelegate. But I cannot find an error handler that gets called when the stream(_:handle:) method doesn't get called

Comment: I see now that the stream delegate is only called when some event happens. So there is no error handler